# How to continue music syncing from MacBook to iPhone (and meta-data in both directions) after upgrading MacBook?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, itunes, backup, music

I was using MacBook Pro A and syncing **its** music to iPhone A. The meta data (last play and star rating) was syncing in **both** direction. All was good.

I then replaced MacBook A with MacBook B, and also started having my music collection on an external drive.

Now I just synced the same iPhone A with the new MacBook B, but noticed that the music sync/backup is now going in the **opposite** direction, from iPhone to MacBook.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, to debug the problem by looking at the size of the backups, I attempted looking at what backups are there, but I am unable to look inside `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync`—not even using `sudo`. What's this about?